# What function will call when view controller is changed to another view controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I have two view controller classes in my application delegate. I can change from one view controller to the next view controller by issuing the method `-pushViewController:animated` of the `navigationController` class and going back to the previous view controller by calling the method `-popViewController:animated`. Now my problem is I want to save some value to the preferences by using `NSUserDefaults` when I go back to the first view controller, and I don't know where should I put:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second view controller, add:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

As the second view disappears and the first view appears, the standard defaults will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

These are all valid depending on exactly when you want to save the info:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated;
```